Convert Image (Camera/Gallery) to 3D View (GLB/OBJ) in Flutter App (Flutter 3.19+ required)
I'm looking to implement a feature in my Flutter app that allows users to select an image from their device (camera or gallery) and convert it into a 3D viewable format like GLB or OBJ.  The ultimate goal is to display this converted image in a 3D view.
My question: Is it possible to achieve image-to-3D conversion directly within a Flutter app?
Here's what I'm aiming for:

User selects an image (camera or gallery) (this implementation done using Image picker)
The app converts the image into a 3D format (GLB or OBJ preferred) in a Flutter App
The converted image is displayed in a 3D view (This point also I can achieve using this latest package, when I convert image to glb or obj file)

I'd like to hear from the Flutter community! Any tips, tricks, or favorite packages for tackling image-to-3D conversion (image to convert .obj or .glb file) would be a huge help.
Thank you.

What have you tried thus far?

Actually, I haven’t found a direct solution for converting an image to a 3D model within Flutter. However, I have tried using the flutter_3d_controller package (version 1.3.1). This package supports 3D model formats like GLB, GLTF, FBX, and OBJ, but it does not support image formats like PNG directly.
